# JQuery UI limiting overlay z-index

Tags: css, jquery-ui, overlay, z-index, modal-dialog

I have a dialog in jQuery UI which is a modal dialog:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({modal:true});
```

I have another div which I want to be ontop of the overlay, however, this div is created before the dialog, and other modal dialogs may be showing up too.

What I want is basically like a "always on top" for that div.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7wGg/1/) explains it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` to your div, so it gets out of the normal page flow and respects the z-index property, see my [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/M7wGg/2/)

```
#mydiv {
    z-index: 1500;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:white;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
```

Rationale: z-index property only has effect on **positioned elements**, so you need one of these:

```
position: relative;
position: absolute;
position: fixed;
```

Comment: What about when I make a dialog out of my div before the overlaying dialog? (e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/M7wGg/3/)

Comment: Use moveToTop method http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-moveToTop for that, see fixed version of your example http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/M7wGg/4/

Comment: I know about the moveToTop (i have an extended widget which implements it), but the problem with your example is that I have to explicitly call the moveToTop method everytime a modal dialog is created. I wanted a way to avoid that.

Comment: You can add a custom class name for your `ui-dialog` div, then apply the desired `z-index` via css forced rule. In this case you won't need to make your div a **positioned** one, so it's better solution. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/M7wGg/6/